# How Parse TCP Stream Consists of Custom-Protocol Packets Using Python

Tags: python, linux, sockets, networking, tcp

Suppose we define a user-level TCP Packets parsing protocol as below:

```
  A User-Level TCP Packet:
  ---------- ------ ---------- ----------------------------
 | F1F2F3F4 | Type |  Length  |         Packet Body        |
  ---------- ------ ---------- ----------------------------

 1. F1F2F3F4: beginning of a packet, hex data (4 bytes)
 2. Type:     denotes what type of this packet (2 bytes)
 3. Length:   how many bytes the packet contains except F1F2F3F4
              Packets may have different length (2 bytes)
 4. PacketBody: Real data a packet contains
```

Say we have a TCP communication pair which exchange data with each other by sending packets in this format. The communicator sends **lots of packets in a time** through a socket, sometimes they even send files in this way.

In C/C++ language I would alloc a buffer big enough to store data which reads from the socket, than scan the **F1F2F3F4** in the buffer and find the **Length** field, 
if the data is less than **Length**, then wait for more.

Now I need to implement this in Python, anybody knows how to do this?

Comment: In Python it's in principle the same, read from socket, scan for F1F2F3F4, get the length, if the data is less than length, wait for more. Do you really have to search for the beginning? How many bits have type and length?

Comment: Both Type and Length are of two bytes.

Answer (score 0):

would look like this:

```
import struct

def recv_full(sock, cnt):
    buf = []
    while cnt>0:
        data = sock.recv(min(10240, cnt))
        buf.append(data)
        cnt -= len(data)
    return ''.join(buf)

def recv_packet(sock):
    header, type, length = struct.unpack('>IHH', recv_full(sock, 8))
    assert header == 0xf1f2f3f4
    return type, recv_full(length - 4)
```

Comment: The problem is there might be dirty data mixing in the stream, and even more bad the packet might be corrupted and become incomplete. So we shouldn't assume the TCP stream are consisting of normal packets one by one.

Comment: how would you like to fix a corrupted packet? Then you have to assume that `f1f2f3f4` is never used in the packet body.

Comment: One way to handle that is to abandon the packet. For example, if a packet has its length field 500 bytes, but real data is only 100 bytes long (which means data is more than 500 bytes but F1F2F3F4 is not found at 501st byte), then we have to abandon that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this

```
import struct

hdr = sock.recv(8, socket.MSG_WAITALL)
(beg, typ, pktlen) = struct.unpack('!IHH', hdr)
if beg == 0xF1F2F3F4:
    body = sock.recv(pktlen, socket.MSG_WAITALL)
else:
    # not expected pkt beginning
```

Comment: recv does not guarantee the given number of bytes

Comment: True -- but i think it's enough to demonstrate the technique, which is what I think the OP was looking for. In any event, he could pass socket.MSG_MSG_WAITALL to the flags parameter to block until that many bytes are read.